# MySQL how to transpose rows by columns

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

My table has its ID, 2 foreign keys and the value; the first foreign key becomes the "ID"

With this query I get what I'm looking for, from **predicate** (it's 2 FK, subject 1 FK) and its value.

`select subject AS 'id', predicate AS 'FK', object AS 'Value' from oer_moretriples where predicate in (3 ,4, 34, 35) order by subject;`

Output

```
| ID | FK | Value |
|----------|:-------------:|------:|
| 847 | 3 | "Michael Tiemeyer" |
| 847 | 4 | "N/A" |
| 1062 | 3 | "Wendy Kurant" |
| 1062 | 4 | "N/A" |
| 1749 | 34 | "Bonnie J. Robinson" |
| 1749 | 35 | "N/A" |
| 7182 | 34 | "J. Franklin Williamson" |
| 7182 | 35 | "N/A" |
| 7183 | 3 | "Molly Zhou" |
| 7183 | 4 | "N/A" |
```

Desired result

```
| ID | author | link |
|----------|:-------------:|------:|
| 847 | "Michael Tiemeyer" | "N/A" |
| 1062 | "Wendy Kurant" | "N/A" |
| 1749 | "Bonnie J. Robinson | "N/A" |
| 7182 | "J. Franklin Williamson" | NULL |
| 7183 | "Molly Zhou" | NULL |
```

Both 3 and 35 have the same name information.
On the other hand 4 and 34 has the link that corresponds to that name.

I explain:
3 -> "Daniel"
4 -> linkDaniel
Now if there is no text in 3, it means that the name is in 35 (35 -> "Daniel") and of course the link in l4 (4 -> linkDaniel), **then** if not 3, search 35 and presents; otherwise there is no "N / A".

At the moment I have this query

```sql
SELECT subject AS 'codeAuthor',
       (CASE WHEN predicate = 3 THEN object END) nameAuthor,
       (CASE WHEN predicate = 4 THEN object END) linkAuthor,
       (CASE WHEN predicate = 35 THEN object END) author,
       (CASE WHEN predicate = 34 THEN object END) link_Author
FROM oer_moretriples
where predicate in (3, 4, 34, 35)
#GROUP BY subject
ORDER BY subject;
```

```
| codeAuthor | nameAuthor | linkAuthor | author | link_Author |
|----------|:-------------:|------:|
| 847 | "Michael Tiemeyer" | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 847 | NULL | "N/A" | NULL | NULL |
| 1062 | "Wendy Kurant" | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1062 | NULL | "N/A" | NULL | NULL |
| 1749 | "Bonnie J. Robinson" | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1749 | NULL | "N/A" | NULL | NULL |
| 7182 | "J. Franklin Williamson" | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 7182 | NULL | "N/A" | NULL | NULL |
| 7183 | "Molly Zhou" | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 7183,NULL,"""N/A""",NULL,NULL |
```

the `GROUP BY` clause simply eliminates the duplicate row, in short I hope you can help me and **understand** what I ask haha

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Use max/min to eliminate the NULLs. General rule is that NULLs are ignored by aggregate functions like MAX/MIN, so adding max/min to case statement will remove NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic you want is:

```
SELECT 
    subject AS codeAuthor,
    MAX(CASE WHEN predicate IN (3, 35) THEN object END) author,
    MAX(CASE WHEN predicate IN (4, 34) THEN object END) link
FROM oer_moretriples
WHERE predicate in (3, 4, 34, 35)
GROUP BY subject
ORDER BY subject
```

Comment: It seems that if, **although** because the use of **MAX**, helps to know which of the 2 (3, 35) has the value (but what happens if both have **max** as applied)
P.S. Thanks I've been busy